# Jquery multiple select boxes limit selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, select

I wanted a select box to have a list of players with two others to add starting 11 as well as one for substitutes.  I have found the following that works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$('#add_starting').click(function() {
return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');
});
$('#remove_starting').click(function() {
return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');
});
 $('#add_subs').click(function() {
return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select3');
});
$('#remove_subs').click(function() {
return !$('#select3 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');
});
});
</script>
```

Here is my html

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select name="from" id="select1" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
                    {exp:clubmanager:player_select} 
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button type="button" id="add_starting" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
                <button type="button" id="remove_starting" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select name="match_players[]" id="select2" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button type="button" id="add_subs" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
                <button type="button" id="remove_subs" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select name="match_subs[]" id="select3" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
            </div>

            </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <!-- Do NOT use name="submit" or id="submit" for the Submit button -->
              <button type="submit" class="btn-u">Update Player</button>
            </div>
            </div>
```

I am looking to add some validation on the select2 box that it won't allow submission if there are less than 11 or more than 11 players.

Comment: Add code example on http://jsfiddle.net please!

Comment: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/27m1e1zp/1/)

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless the question is about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
        if ( $('#select2').find('option').length != 11 ) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent submit

            console.log("Not posting!");
        } else {
            console.log("Posting!");
        }
    });
```

Also, you don't have to `remove()` an element before doing `appendTo()` since an element can only have one parent anyway. So this will work fine:

```
$('#select1 option:selected').appendTo('#select2');
```

Full example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/hm2hjfvj/)

Comment: Just tested this and works great. Do you have any ideas how I can add an error so if someone tries to post it will tell them that they haven't selected enough players, and/or if I can have something above the two select lists that say how many players currently selected.

Comment: Sure, just create a hidden div like ```<div id="error_message" class="alert alert-danger alert-error">``` with an error message and do ```$("#error_message").show();``` when a user attempts to submit invalid data. I updated the example on JSFiddle.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing, but the error message is appearing when I load the page and won't display again after that.

Comment: Make it ```display:none``` and do ```.show()``` when needed. Check the jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry forgot to update the CSS.  And apologies for being a pain but if I cancel error and submit again with the wrong number it doesn't display the error again.

Comment: Well, don't allow a user to close it then =). Also, you can hide it when any form input changes. Updated the fiddle.

Comment: Is there anyway of selecting all in the select2 and select3 on submit.  I am using this as part of a form and just noticed that it only passes the selected values to the form on submit.

Comment: Sure, do ```$('#select2 option').prop('selected', true);``` or ```$('#select2 option').attr('selected', 'selected');``` on submit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess from select option 1, you are adding players to select option 2. So its better you set validation on select option1, and check then and there whether the select option 2 has 11 players(options) or not.

You can also add validation on `add_subs` for substitute players.

```
$('#select2 option,#add_subs').on('click',function(){
   if ( $('#select2 option').length == 11 ) {
      return false;
   }
else{
 //code to append
}
});
```